# No UFW logs at syslog

Tags: networking, wireless, firewall, ufw, logs

I'm using here the UFW as a basic protection. When I'm using the wi-fi from the college I get some UFW block (which is normal, because the firewall is ON).

But strangely, I'm not getting any UFW logs at home (it used to get a few, but now there's no blocks).

Here is some info about `ufw status verbose`

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: reject (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

Is there something wrong with my router or PC?

EDIT: I'm including some UFW blocks logs from syslog:

```
Mar 21 10:45:16 IBM-5100 kernel: [   98.436052] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=23.216.171.218 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=33520 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=52722 WINDOW=530 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Mar 21 10:45:16 IBM-5100 kernel: [   98.449193] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=23.216.171.218 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=49314 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=52721 WINDOW=645 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Mar 21 10:45:17 IBM-5100 kernel: [   98.570999] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=23.216.171.218 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=58273 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=52723 WINDOW=619 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Mar 21 10:45:17 IBM-5100 kernel: [   98.802973] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=23.216.171.218 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=58274 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=52723 WINDOW=619 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Mar 21 10:45:17 IBM-5100 kernel: [   98.837751] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=23.216.171.218 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=47387 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=52725 WINDOW=491 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Mar 21 10:45:17 IBM-5100 kernel: [   98.899208] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=23.216.171.218 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=18711 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=52724 WINDOW=492 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Mar 21 10:45:17 IBM-5100 kernel: [   98.916786] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=23.216.171.218 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=33521 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=52722 WINDOW=530 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Mar 21 10:45:17 IBM-5100 kernel: [   98.926664] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=23.216.171.218 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=49315 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=52721 WINDOW=645 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Mar 21 10:45:17 IBM-5100 kernel: [   99.035012] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=23.216.171.218 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=58275 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=52723 WINDOW=619 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
    Mar 21 10:45:17 IBM-5100 kernel: [   99.500770] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=23.216.171.218 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=58276 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=52723 WINDOW=619 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
Mar 21 01:04:26 IBM-5100 kernel: [ 2282.633953] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=91.189.92.10 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=29648 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=34955 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
Mar 21 01:04:26 IBM-5100 kernel: [ 2282.714411] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=91.189.92.11 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=46 ID=27150 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=45527 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
Mar 21 01:04:26 IBM-5100 kernel: [ 2282.633953] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=91.189.92.10 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=29648 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=34955 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
Mar 21 01:04:26 IBM-5100 kernel: [ 2282.714411] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=1c:6f:65:ae:63:5e:00:24:01:97:d7:32:08:00 SRC=91.189.92.11 DST=192.168.0.136 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=46 ID=27150 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=45527 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Thank you guys for helping me.

Comment: Do you have some log from `ufw` in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @2707974 Just added spme logs in the question. Also, these logs were found in syslog.2

Answer (score 0):

Practically this is the same logs.

Try with command

```
sudo ufw logging high
```

After that check logs in `/var/log/ufw.log`

Comment: Well, right now there is a lot of UFW logs, but there's only audit and allow logs, no block logs. Is that normal?

Comment: If you block some traffic is not normal. Do you have any rule?

Comment: No, I just changed the profile to Public (allow out and reject in). Are you sure that blocking connection is not normal?